# VideoJs Control bar doesn't shows up on click or hover on smart tv and some mobile browsers

Tags: javascript, jquery, video.js

I have initialized my player with this code. It works fine on everything except on smart tv and some phone browser. My suspected guess was that it is due to the touch events on those devices. But I have already used every turnaround but none of it worked.

```
videoplayer = videojs(mId+'-'+season+'-'+episode, {
                        height: '100%',
                        width: '100%',
                        poster: poster,
                        controls: true ,
                        autoplay:false,
                        preload: 'auto',
                        sources: nsrc,
                        techOrder: ['html5', 'flash'],
                        plugins: {
                            chromecast:{
                             appId:'F6399642',
                             metadata:{
                               title: mId,
                               subtitle:'Synopsis display on tech wrapper',
                             }
                          },
                            videoJsResolutionSwitcher: {
                                default: 480,
                                dynamicLabel: false
                            }

                        }
                    });
```

I have currently used this function but it also didn't worked. I am stuck on this error for so long

```
 //Fixing Tv Player
               videoplayer.on('click touchstart', function(){ 
              videoplayer.controlBar.addClass('vjs-hidden'); 
            });

            videoplayer.on('click', function(){ 
              videoplayer.controlBar.removeClass('vjs-hidden'); 
            });
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After lot of head banging I found the fix. The bug was inside chromecast plugin for videojs and I fixed it after disabling chromecast plugin for unknown browsers.